# Azure upgrade domain, domain count

Tags: deployment, azure, upgrade, manual

We are using a manual azure deployment strategy and then "walking the upgrade domains" we have in turn.
This is done using a combination of powershell scripts and Cerebrata cmdlets.

What we are finding is that we have 2 upgrade domains. We expect to walk domains 0 and 1 as its a zero based count. However we end up having to walk upgrade domains 0, 1 and 2.

We see a similar affect when we do this through the Azure management portal. In that we have to "Upgrade" 3 times rather than the two we are expecting.

My question is does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: You say you have to upgrade 3 times, you mean or it doesn't work correctly or do you mean that there are instances in all 3?  Could it be a problem with your looping code?

Comment: I have call or initiate (depending if I am using code or the portal) "walk upgrade domain" 3 times. If I only call it twice, I am left with the portal waiting for me to update the final domain.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find documentation for it, so I can't be sure, but IIRC, this is by design. The first call starts the first update domain. The second call marks the first as complete and starts the second. The last call marks the last update domain (and thus the entire update) as complete. Again, I can't remember this for sure, but I think you'll see the same thing in the web portal. You'll have to click the button *n*+1 times where *n* is the number of update domains.

Comment: Thanks for feeding back. I understand your not making a definitive statement but what you say makes sense.